# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS offline

Tags: ros, roscore, offline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to run a ROS "network" offline? For example, on a computer without an internet connection how can one start a roscore and other nodes that only communicate with each other on that machine?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38707/ros-offline/) by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 600 on 2012-07-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, just set your ROS_MASTER_URI to localhost (which I believe is the default).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) on 2012-07-12**:
Thank you very much!

**Comment by [nirge](https://answers.ros.org/users/67591/nirge/) on 2021-01-12**:
This occurs in kinetic and melodic as well. added ROS_MASTER_URI to localhost and it solved it.